# Use 1.5 V Lithium batteries instead of AA alkaline?

Tags: batteries, camera

My PowerShot A720 IS digital camera (from 2008) permits AA-size 1.2 V NiMH or regular disposable AA alkaline batteries. Can I use AA-size 1.5 V Lithium batteries?

The manual ([pdf](http://www.nait.ca/libresources/manuals/Canon-PowerShotA720IS.pdf)) warns against nickel-cadmium, but doesn't mention Lithium:

> This camera uses AA-size alkaline batteries or Canon AA-size NiMH batteries. While it is possible to use a size nickel-cadmium batteries, performance is unreliable and their use is not recommended.

Thoughts?

**EDIT**: [Here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000DC4EL) are the proposed Lithium batteries.

Comment: Primary Lithium cells, rather than rechargable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using 1.5 volt AA lithium cells in my Nikon camera for some time with no problems.  As long as the voltage is correct, I don't see any reason not to use them.

Comment: Interesting. I was curious about AA lithium, but had never used them before. Looking at this datasheet: http://www.varta-microbattery.com/applications/mb_data/documents/data_sheets/DS6117.pdf , I find that they seem to be rated for \$1mA-10mA\$ loads, which is quite different from what alkaline and NiMH batteries support.

Comment: @jonk - Hi - FYI the battery you have linked is *not* a normal AA battery; it states "Nominal Voltage ... **3V**" so it is different to what *Peter Bennett* is talking about.

Comment: @SamGibson: Thanks. I had just noticed that! I need to look at the right datasheets!

Answer (score 0):

Canon's comment about the reliability of NiCd seems to be voltage related because NiCd has about [half](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/rising_internal_resistance) the output resistance of NiMH so I would think they are superior for high-current flash-type discharges and optical zoom motors.

Under that assumption your 1.5V Lithium cells would be fine.

Comment: LiIon -> Lithium. quite different beasts.